# Adding both x and y data point labels on only start and end of plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I would like to add labels for my data points, but would like to add both the x and y value for only the start and end data point. With geom_text, I can only add either x or y for all of my data points. Is there a way for me to achieve what I would like to on my plot?

Some code of my data:

```
Area <- structure(list(Cumulative.increase = c(14.69, 37.21, 50.72, 51.81, 57.05, 57.98, 72.65, 79.93, 95.82, 
97.25, 115.69, 147.69, 155.82, 161.03, 169.9, 185.31, 190.57, 194.82), 
Reclaim.date = structure(c(13610, 13722, 13994, 14010, 14154, 14218, 14362, 14426, 14730, 14826, 15082, 
15850, 16170, 16378, 16650, 16922, 17370, 17546), class = "Date")), 
.Names = c("Cumulative.increase",  "Reclaim.date"), 
row.names = c(NA, 18L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is the code I now have for my plot.

```
    plot1 <- ggplot(Area, aes(x=Reclaim.date, y=Cumulative.increase))+
      geom_area() + 
      geom_text(data = Area, aes(x=Reclaim.date, y=Cumulative.increase, 
         label = Reclaim.date))
```

In this case, I would like to include labels of both `Date` and `Cumulative.increase` in the plot, but only for the first and last data point.

I checked some posts about this, some of them use ifelse to choose their specific points, but as I would like the first and last points, I'm not sure what I should do. Thanks a lot.

Here is what my graph currently looks like, with only the x/y axis (which is the x-axis in this case) and also showing labels for every point but I would like only the first and last point.

[image]

Comment: @ Sheena Chung check these links out please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Some ideas for making this more reproducible: See if one of the included R [datasets](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/r-built-in-data-sets) can be used to demonstrate the issue instead of your data so we can run the code you are trying, and remove the code for title, labels, theme and any other pieces not relevant to your question.

Comment: I tried adding some codes for a reproducible example and removing not related codes. The geom_text part is the one I am not sure about. Is the code I included enough for a reproducible example? Thanks in advance. @Tjebo

Comment: @BrianStamper this is getting spooky. Is there an algorithm which is flagging some specific key words??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way with `dplyr`

```
require(dplyr)
  data_text <- Area %>% filter(row_number() %in% c(1,n()))
```

I have done this with row_number, because your previous code included several groups. You want to group by your variable first using `group_by`.

Then use this new data frame for your plot

```
 ggplot(Area, aes(x=Reclaim.date, y=Cumulative.increase))+
  geom_area() + 
  geom_text(data = data_text, aes(x=Reclaim.date, y=Cumulative.increase, label = Reclaim.date))
```

[image]

Comment: I see, thanks a lot! Is it also possible to add the y-value on the graph or does the labelling only allow either one of the two (x/y) values?

Comment: @SheenaChung of course - easiest in a second geom_text : currently you specify the x and y coordinates for the “x-labels”. do the same but with the “y labels”. You might need to add a position adjusting parameter because the two labels will overlay

Comment: Oh, should have thought of that! Thank you very much!